# Gorm query formatting breaking with `%` - "expected 0 arguments, got 1"

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am getting the error "expected 0 arguments, got 1" querying postgres with the following line:

```golang
db = db.Where("LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%?%')", nameSearch)
```

Which works when I hard code values into it like so:

```golang
db = db.Where("LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%some-value%')")
```

Can anyone spot my issue here as I have many where conditions similarly formatted that work but this one, with the extra `%` is breaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a quick look at the docs, it seems like you should add the wildcards to the `nameSearch` variable: [as shown here](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#String-Conditions)

> db.Where("name LIKE ?", "%jin%").Find(&users)
> // SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%jin%';

So that would be:

```
db.Where("LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(?)", fmt.Sprintf("%%%s%%", nameSearch))
```

Of course, you can just use `"%" + nameSearch + "%"`